# Miner bees vs raised beds

Tags: pests, raised-beds

Last yard some strange ground bees opened up shop in my front yard. I did a little research and determined they're miner bees. Apparently they don't sting and are generally helpful in a similar way to honey bees, so I left them alone. This year I added some raised beds in that same area, and I'm wondering if I'm going to regret that decision.

It's early in the season, and I've only planted a few things, but the tunneling and the piling of dirt is making me worried that they're going to harm my vegetables. Either by smothering my small seedlings with the spoils of their digging, or maybe harming the roots with their tunnels.

Is there common wisdom about miner bees? Any advice is welcome.

[image: miner bee holes]

[image: a miner bee at work]

[image: more miner bee tunnels]

Comment: They are solitary (though they sometimes make a colony of individual nests, like your picture) so there is no danger you will end up with a "termite mound" of bees. IMO you will gain more from their pollination activity than you lose from the occasional uprooted seedling.

Comment: I have had them and they never stung .But , they did seem to get agitated if any one stood in front of the hole.